# Gnuplot, epslatex, name change

Tags: gnuplot, sharelatex, epslatex

I made a code in gnuplot that produces the outputfiles trykk.eps and trykk.tex  And i have made the following latex code(see under).This works, but when i change **the name** of my gnuplot outputfiles to **trykk1.eps** and **trykk1.tex**  and the latex code line to `\resizebox{1.0\textwidth}{!}{\input{trykk1}}` the latex code no longer works. It displays the x and y axis but the picture is gone

[image].

And i have no clue why. Can someone help me?

[Latex files trykk.eps and trykk.tex](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B9CEsYCSSZUSdFV4RGZIXzdJTG8&usp=sharing)

Using sharelatex.com if that makes any difference.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{svg}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \resizebox{1.0\textwidth}{!}{\input{trykk}}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at file `trkyy.tex` (line 114), it says

```
\put(0,0){\includegraphics{trykk}}%
```

which means that it's not enough to change file name, but also its contents. Change this line (in `trkyy1.tex`) to `put(0,0){\includegraphics{trykk1}}%` and it will work again.